# Encrypted and unencrypted appSettings - is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, web-config

I need to split the `appSettings` section into `web.config` and an external config file. The settings under `web.config` must remain unencrypted, whereas the settings in the configuration file must be encrypted.

Is this possible to accomplish at all? I get the configuration error  "Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider'.

```
<!-- web.config -->
<appSettings file="AppSettings.config">
  <add key="URL" value="stackoverflow.com" />
</appSettings>

<!-- external config file -->
<appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData>...</EncryptedData>
</appSettings>
```

I am using this command to encrypt the required settings. I then move the encrypted data to the external configuration file:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "appSettings" "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the WEB.CONFIG is a protected file by OS, I mean, no one can download it or view it. So, I think is unnecessary to have it encrypted.

And since WEB.CONFIG is a shared file (sometimes it can be read more than once depending of the amount of access in server), keep it encrypted is not possible.